# How to make an update in nested documents by property path and array of strings?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Im trying to update/replace an single item from array of strings. How can I do it in mongodb?

I tried using mongodb version >= 4, mongoose >= 5 and nodejs >= v12.2.0.

This is my update:

```
{
          _id: bot._id,
          intents: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "car",
              examples: "blue",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $set: { 'intents.$[outer].examples.$[inner]': "yellow" },
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [
            { 'outer.name': "car" },
            { 'inner.examples': "blue" },
          ],
        },
```

This is a single document:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cff64bacea5f52b74cefd57"),
        "name" : "a",
        "language" : "en",
        "userId" : "auth0|5ce2ce9fb0ada80ea32d7643",
        "cloudBotId" : "4327a229-ec34-423e-b9ad-4778cf74b0a0",
        "intents" : [
                {
                        "examples" : [
                                "blue"
                        ],
                        "name" : "car"
                },
                {
                        "examples" : [
                                "red"
                        ],
                        "name" : "bike"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I expect to replace "blue" to "yellow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just near... no needs to add examples in your arrayFilters, just use inner :

```
        {
          _id: bot._id,
          intents: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "car",
              examples: "blue",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $set: { 'intents.$[outer].examples.$[inner]': "yellow" },
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [
            { 'outer.name': "car" },
            { 'inner': "blue" },
          ],
        }
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Since I have `$elemMatch` query name "car" I removed from `$elemMatch` the `examples: "blue"` and from arrayFilters also `{"outer.name": "car"}` and for the last I changed the `$set` to `$set: { 'intents.$.examples.$[inner]': "yellow" }`

Do you think is good?

Comment: But I think have more performance having `examples: "blue"` because if I have some intent.name eq `car` and none in examples with `blue`, probably I will skip the arrayFilter part doing operations.